# WPF Separator not showing in ToolBar OverflowPanel

Tags: wpf, overflow, toolbar, separator

it seems that a WPF Separator doesn't show up in a ToolBar's Overflow panel when you shrink the size of the toolbar; is there someway to make it show?  (I can get around it by using an empty colored label, but I'd still like to know why separators don't work).

An example: create a new WPF project with in the mainwindow.xaml:

```
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ToolBar HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="toolBar1">
      <Button Content="ASDF" />
      <Button Content="ASDF" />
      <Button Content="ASDF" />
      <Button Content="ASDF" />
      <Button Content="ASDF" />
      <Button Content="ASDF" />
      <Button Content="ASDF" />
      <Button Content="ASDF" />
      <Separator />
      <Button Content="ASDF" />
      <Button Content="ASDF" />
      <Button Content="ASDF" />
      <Button Content="ASDF" />
      <Button Content="ASDF" />
      <Button Content="ASDF" />
      <Button Content="ASDF" />
      <Button Content="ASDF" />
      <Button Content="ASDF" />
    </ToolBar>
  </Grid>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My problem was answered on MSDN; you need to wrap it in a grid and rotate it 90 degrees:

```
 <Grid Width="10">
     <Separator>
         <Separator.LayoutTransform>
             <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
         </Separator.LayoutTransform>
     </Separator>
 </Grid>
```

However in my actual project I didn't need to do the rotation for some reason or other.

Comment: If you manually set the width to 10 of a Separator you will see it is a horizontal line by default instead of a vertical line.

Answer (score 0):

Please try it this is showing separator with overflow and you can set the overflow with each element by "overflowmode" property.

```
<ToolBarPanel>
        <ToolBar ToolBarTray.IsLocked="True"  Name="toolBar1">
            <ToolBar Band="1" BandIndex="1">
                <Button Content="ASDF" />

                <Button Content="ASDF" />

                <Button Content="ASDF" />

            </ToolBar>
            <Separator/>
            <ToolBar Band="2" BandIndex="1">
                <Button Content="ASDF" />
                <Button Content="ASDF" />

            </ToolBar>
            <Separator/>
            <ToolBar Band="2" BandIndex="2">
                <Button Content="ASDF" />
                <Button Content="ASDF" />
                <Button Content="ASDF" ToolBar.OverflowMode="Always"/>
                <Button Content="ASDF" ToolBar.OverflowMode="Always" />

            </ToolBar>
        </ToolBar>
    </ToolBarPanel>
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: Sorry, I want the look to be like it is originally, with one overflow toolbar, not multiple.